# Is a druid hit by Feeblemind able to use wild shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape

In the description of *feeblemind*, it states that a creature that fails the saving throw cannot cast spells, use magic items or communicate. But a druid's *wild shape* is none of those.

Would a druid hit by *feeblemind* still be able to use this ability?

My reasoning for asking is that a character might still need to have some measure of intelligence to be able to discern the need for the use of wild shape, as well as to choose what form to turn into, etc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You've already answered your own question.  Wild shape isn't a spell nor a magic item, so *feeblemind* doesn't stop a druid from doing it.  Furthermore, *Feeblemind* doesn't lower Wisdom, which is both the primary attribute for druids and a mental attribute most beasts have bonuses to (as opposed to Intelligence, which is not more than 2, and Charisma, which is often somewhat below 10), and so there's not even any fluff reason to think *feeblemind* would interfere with a druid's ability to be an animal.

Answer (score -9):

It's basically one of these things that's really up to the DM, people will tell you definitely 'x' or definitely 'y' and battle to the end on who's 'right', but ultimately they're both right... just depends on the game.

Answer (score -10):

No.

A normal animal does not have the ability to use magic. *Wild shape* is a magical ability, and all beasts with spell-like abilities have always had higher intelligence. *Feeblemind* is a powerful spell that specifically negates the use of magic, and whether or not it's an inherent trait, RAI: intelligence should be required to use *wild shape*. That's why druids maintain their mental stats in animal form.

Answer (score -11):

I say no, as it's a magical change and feeblemind negates the ability to use magic and magic items.

Comment: The wording is important: "The creature can't cast spells, activate magic items, understand language, or communicate in any intelligible way." Wild Shape is not a spell, it's an ability and there is nothing here that says you can't activate abilities. Otherwise Feeblemind would prevent a Phantom Rogue from using his `Wails from the Grave` ability and basically prevent *any* magic from being used. Feeblemind's wording is explicitly not saying that but instead listing precise things you cannot do.